# Keyboard Functionality implementation

Tags: c#, keyboard

I made a keyboard with some functionalities but i have no idea how to add control functionality.This keyboard is to be used in touch screen.Using the code given at  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/touchscreenkeyboard.aspx

any idea what functionality ctrl will perform ?

Secondly I want this to do actual work like if i click A on this it should write a anywhere as if original key at physical keyboard was pressed.in other words i want to trigger keyboard events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send keyboard commands to windows you will need to pinvoke the [SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/sendinput.html) or [SendKeys](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/sendkeys.html) function in user32.dll
There is a nice [project](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) on codeplex doing exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at (and work with) the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) (for winforms) and [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) (for native). And you should also look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx).

Comment: What if i create new form and just add Buttons to it for all keyboard and then use Send Keys in that buttons this will tell me which button is pressed

Comment: or I have to use xy position as this would be working on touch screen